# nodejs: how to ignore the "import" error while testing file with mocha?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

let's say I have a nodejs project. In the app.js file I have to read some property file with the propertiesReader.

```
var propertiesReader = require('properties-reader')
var property = getPropertyFile('/fileName.properties')
```

The thing is this fileName.properties does not exist in my Host PC but only on the target machine.

When I run this code on the target machine everything is fine but when I tried to require('./app.js') in my mocha test file, the mocha reports error that this property file does not exist. So it says an exception outside of the test frame has been raised.

I tried:

```
try{
    const test = require('./app.js')
}catch(err)
{}
```

But the exception will still be shown and it messed up with my test result message.

Is there any method that I can 'import' this app.js without printing these 'import' errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use env.

```
if(process.env == 'remote'){
    var property = getPropertyFile('/fileName.properties')
}

$> NODE_ENV=local node app.js
```

In this case, the file would not be required.

Comment: thnx, on my PC process.env is actually a dictionary and it contains a lot variables. But I manage to use the process.env['PWD'] to identify if it's under a testing environment.